# UVM- can single driver and a single monitor be connectes to multi interfaces?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Can a single driver and a single monitor be connected to multiple interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. but not usually a good idea for re-usability. If the interfaces are required to be used together, then it may make more sense.